# Android and Google Wallet - mandatory for one time purchase?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, android-pay

Is the **Google Wallet** [online payment system](https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=sierra&passive=1200&continue=https://checkout.google.com/main&followup=https://checkout.google.com/main&scc=1&authuser=0) on Android phones mandatory for e.g. movie, songs or game levels purchases in a similar way the Apple’s **In-App-Purchase** is on iOS?

According to the information [here](http://www.android.com/us/developer-content-policy.html?phpMyAdmin=cfc2644bd9c947213a0141747c2608b0) “*Developers offering additional content, goods, or services for an application downloaded from Android Market must offer an authorized Payment Processor as the payment option*“.

1. Our understanding is that if user has installed an application, which plays movies and users pay per single movie view application needs using the Google Wallet otherwise it can be removed from Google Play. Is that correct?
2. Similar situation is within game if user wants to pay for the additional level. Is that correct?

For subscriptions it is not required to use the Google Wallet (again the similar situation is on the iOS).

STeN

Answer (score 2):

I had an app that had LogiaMobile billing integrated and was rejected from Google Play for that very reason (it was in Sept 2011). The app tried to bill users when they wanted to download videos.

Find a good explanation about the policies in this [Techcrunch article](http://techcrunch.com/2012/08/01/google-tightens-up-app-policy-gets-stricter-on-namingicon-payments-privacy-ads-and-spam-rules-developer-letter/)

My advice would be to always integrate Google In-App billing (now v3 is far more confortable to work with).

I hope this is what you were asking for :)

Answer (score 1):

'Google Wallet' is a confusing name, because it may refer to different thing. First there is the Google Wallet *app* that lets you pay with your phone via NFC. You certainly don't need this to buy things from the Play Store and it is supported only in the US, and only on a limited number of devices. Google Wallet also refers to Google's online payment system (aka Google Checkout). You need to register your credit card with that in order to make purchases on Android. It serves as the 'authorized Payment Processor' in most case. Other ones being carrier billing on supported carriers.

Comment: Thanks, we are aware about difference between NFC wallet and the online payment system. The possible confusion is made by Google, since they renamed Checkout to the Wallet. To rephrase the question: “Do we need to use Google Wallet online payment system for purchases as specified above in my question”?

Comment: The only other option is carrier billing, so generally, yes. There are some corner cases, but you might have to consult a lawyer for those. For in-app purchases you need to use the Google-provided API anyway and it will do right thing by connecting to the Google Play Store on the device.